# How can I load nested array into Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

How can I load nested array into Google BigQuery. For example

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Subhayu

Answer (score 3):

I have quickly tried to come up with some code. Don't know whether it would exactly solve your use case. But you will have to do something similar.

Below is the Scala code to create the table programmatically

```
  val tableId = "_geometry_" 
  val tableReference = new TableReference().setTableId(tableId)
  val table = new Table().setSchema(new TableSchema().setFields(
    List(
      new TableFieldSchema().setName("geo").setType("RECORD").setFields(
        List(
          new TableFieldSchema().setName("type").setType("STRING"),
          new TableFieldSchema().setName("coordinates").setType("RECORD").setMode("REPEATED").setFields(
            List(
              new TableFieldSchema().setName("index").setType("RECORD").setMode("REPEATED").setFields(
                List(
                   new TableFieldSchema().setName("sub_index").setType("RECORD").setMode("REPEATED").
                     setFields(List( new TableFieldSchema().setName("_0").setType("STRING"),
                   new TableFieldSchema().setName("_1").setType("STRING")))
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      ))
    )
  ).setTableReference(tableReference)
```

After creating the table you can load the data from csv file or you can also programmatically insert the data.

This would create a table schema like this

[image]

Comment: Please can you send me the code output - ie; the schema format? I will use it then for UI based loading into BigQuery.

Comment: unfortunately your solution did not work. It's giving the sam error -"location.geo.coordinates[0], nested arrays not allowed"

Comment: As i told, the code is just a reference for you, i may not work exactly for your use case. But the given code works fine and generates the table as shown. You will have to modify the code for your purpose

Comment: I want the code to resolve Nested Array as shown in my question.'0' and '1' are array index which can not be defined as Json element like string "_0" and "_1".        Any help from anyone please?

Comment: @Subhayu you need to transform that in your programming language, you cannot do exactly like you say in BQ. You need to change the indexes into JSON and BiqQuery accepted format.

Comment: @Pentium10 - The snippet I have pasted that is a part of JSON itself - it's a twitter standard output. Which contains several other fields including this "geo".I have prepared a schema of 400+ lines for the entire JSON. And that worked,only if I make this nested array into single level array like {"coordinates":[float,float]}".But with multiple level of arrays(as shown above), it is not working. Now let me assume you have made you understood.

Comment: Also I can not change the incoming JSON format. So I have to have a solution to accept nested array format.I would suggest any BigQuery expert to first prepare a sample JSON with exactly what I have embedded above and try out a solution.