# load nested arrays into bigquery

Tags: arrays, json, google-bigquery

I have data in JSON format with nested arrays in them. Here's an example:

```
"data": {"events": [[1, 1271, 518, 945], [1, 1287, 495, 963],...
```

the length of the sub-arrays can be 3 or 4, and the first number is the data type (there are around 30 different ones). Is there any way to load this data to bigQuery without transforming into a dictionary 'record'?

Thanks,
Yaron

--EDIT--

there's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686156/how-can-i-load-nested-array-into-google-bigquery) question, that has a workaround, but there there is a fixed length subarray, so not applicable I guess..

Comment: it is not clear what final table is expected - provide example!

Answer (score 2):

It might be wrong direction, as it is not entirely clear what is your final goal, but let me try to help you
Somehow, I feel your destination table is expected to be something like below

```
type    metric1 metric2 metric3  
   1       1271     518     945  
   1       1287     495     963
```

So, my recommendation is to make your it in two steps

**Step 1** - load your data as CSV with just one field - let's say table `theTable` with field `data`

```
                              data
 {"data": {"events": [[1, 1271, 518, 945], [1, 1287, 495, 963]]}}
 {"data": {"events": [[2, 111, 222, 333], [3, 444, 555, 666], [4, 777, 888, 999]]}}
```

**Step 2** - process `theTable` to produce expected schema (see on top of the answer) and save into final table. You can use below query for this

```
SELECT
  NTH(1, SPLIT(y)) AS type,
  NTH(2, SPLIT(y)) AS metric1,
  NTH(3, SPLIT(y)) AS metric2,
  NTH(4, SPLIT(y)) AS metric3,
FROM (
  SELECT 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(COALESCE(y0, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6), '[', ''), ']', '') AS y  
  FROM (
    SELECT
      IF(k=0, JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.data.events[0]'), NULL) AS y0,
      IF(k=1, JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.data.events[1]'), NULL) AS y1,
      IF(k=2, JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.data.events[2]'), NULL) AS y2,
      IF(k=3, JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.data.events[3]'), NULL) AS y3,
      IF(k=4, JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.data.events[4]'), NULL) AS y4,
      IF(k=5, JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.data.events[5]'), NULL) AS y5,
      IF(k=6, JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.data.events[6]'), NULL) AS y6,
    FROM theTable AS a
    CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT k FROM (SELECT 0 AS k), (SELECT 1 AS k), (SELECT 2 AS k), 
      (SELECT 3 AS k), (SELECT 4 AS k), (SELECT 5 AS k), (SELECT 6 AS k)
    ) AS b
  )
  HAVING NOT y IS NULL
)
```

The result will be

```
type    metric1 metric2 metric3  
   1       1271     518     945  
   1       1287     495     963  
   2        111     222     333  
   3        444     555     666  
   4        777     888     999
```

As you can see - this particular query supports up to 7 sub-arrays, but you can decrease or increase this by changing code in three places

#1

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(COALESCE(y0, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6), '[', ''), ']', '') AS y
```

#2

```
IF(k=0, JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.data.events[0]'), NULL) AS y0,
IF(k=1, JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.data.events[1]'), NULL) AS y1,
IF(k=2, JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.data.events[2]'), NULL) AS y2,
IF(k=3, JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.data.events[3]'), NULL) AS y3,
IF(k=4, JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.data.events[4]'), NULL) AS y4,
IF(k=5, JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.data.events[5]'), NULL) AS y5,
IF(k=6, JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.data.events[6]'), NULL) AS y6,
```

#3

```
SELECT k FROM (SELECT 0 AS k), (SELECT 1 AS k), (SELECT 2 AS k), 
(SELECT 3 AS k), (SELECT 4 AS k), (SELECT 5 AS k), (SELECT 6 AS k)
```

Finally, to test just transformation logic, w/o loading actual data - you can use below script

```
SELECT
  NTH(1, SPLIT(y)) AS type,
  NTH(2, SPLIT(y)) AS metric1,
  NTH(3, SPLIT(y)) AS metric2,
  NTH(4, SPLIT(y)) AS metric3,
FROM (
  SELECT 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(COALESCE(y0, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6), '[', ''), ']', '') AS y  
  FROM (
    SELECT
      IF(k=0, JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.data.events[0]'), NULL) AS y0,
      IF(k=1, JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.data.events[1]'), NULL) AS y1,
      IF(k=2, JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.data.events[2]'), NULL) AS y2,
      IF(k=3, JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.data.events[3]'), NULL) AS y3,
      IF(k=4, JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.data.events[4]'), NULL) AS y4,
      IF(k=5, JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.data.events[5]'), NULL) AS y5,
      IF(k=6, JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.data.events[6]'), NULL) AS y6,
    FROM (
    SELECT data FROM 
      (SELECT '{"data": {"events": [[1, 1271, 518, 945], [1, 1287, 495, 963]]}}' AS data),
      (SELECT '{"data": {"events": [[2, 111, 222, 333], [3, 444, 555, 666], [4, 777, 888, 999]]}}' AS data) 
    ) AS a
    CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT k FROM (SELECT 0 AS k), (SELECT 1 AS k), (SELECT 2 AS k), 
      (SELECT 3 AS k), (SELECT 4 AS k), (SELECT 5 AS k), (SELECT 6 AS k)
    ) AS b
  )
  HAVING NOT y IS NULL
)
```

Hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to load arrays of arrays directly; you need to use a record to wrap the inner level of arrays. The reference for standard SQL touches on this (albeit in terms of the language itself, not loading data): https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/arrays#building_arrays_of_arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to avoid having to run a transformation on the data to turn it into records/structs. Is there a way to upload this nested array as a string/text blob?

Comment: This past question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660579/bigquery-create-column-of-json-datatype You can load it as a string, then use BigQuery's JSON functions to extract that parts that you want as part of the query.

Comment: I have a summary problem, I just want to load the nested array into BQ. The json line looks like  `{"data": {"events": [[1, 1271, 518, 945], [1, 1287, 495, 963]]}}` I want to load this into BQ